# nil conf error while starting peer in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Error =>

```
InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/fastfabric/scripts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hulu/users/Admin@hulu/msp/: Setup error: nil conf reference
```

I am trying to start fastfabric as mentioned in https://github.com/cgorenflo/fabric/tree/fastfabric-1.4. When I run ./run_storage.sh , I get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

your configtxgen and cryptogen version may be not mached. Version of binaries should be 1.4.0. use the following command to download fabric binary version 1.4.0:

> curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 1.4.0 1.4.0 0.4.18 -s -d

it will only download the binaries.Then place the binaries to

> fabric/fastfabric/scripts/bin

folder. Hope this will solve your problem